# How to get full URL with parameter of SharePoint upload multiple documents iframe

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I need to get full URL with parameter of SharePoint upload multiple documents iframe.I added custom button "Upload Multiple Documents" on my application page.I want to open SharePoint upload multiple documents iframe on that button click event.

Firebug not works for me to get URL of multiple document upload iframe.